# How do I set the default value to a hidden input box using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can do I set the default value to a hidden input box in html page using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You can try like this `viewbag.HiddenItem="This is a hidden value";`  and `<input type="hidden" id="YourHiddenId" name="YourHiddenName" value="@Viewbag.HiddenItem">` Or also like this `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.YourModel, new { Value = "@Viewbag.HiddenItem" })`

Answer (score 1):

> Seems you are trying to set `hidden value` on `asp.net MVC`. You could
> try below way.

***`Model:`***

```
public class HiddenValueModel
    {
        public int HiddenValueId { get; set; }
        public String HiddenValueName{ get; set; }
    }
```

***`Load Default View From Controller:`***

```
 public IActionResult HiddenValueExample()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

***`View:`***

```
@model MVCApps.Models.HiddenValueModel


@{ ViewBag.Title = " "; }

<h2>Hidden Value Example </h2>
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm("HiddenValueExamplePost", "controllerName"))
{


    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr><th>HiddenValueName </th><td id="HiddenValueName"> @Html.TextBoxFor(r => Model.HiddenValueName, new { @class = "form-control" })</td></tr>
        <tr><th>HiddenValue Id Which Is Hidden</th><td id="HiddenValueId"><input type="hidden" id="HiddenValueId" name="HiddenValueId" value="01052022" /></tr>
    </table>


    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:1091px" />
}
```

> ***`Note:`*** Here you could see `HiddenValueId` we have set the value into the feild and keep that hidden. But when you would submitted the
> value to the `controller` it would be there. Additionally, if you want to bind the `hidden value` from your backend you can use this way `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HiddenValueId, new { @value = Model.HiddenValueId} )`. You could also have a
> look more details on [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.hidden?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2)

***`Submit Value To Controller:`***

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult HiddenValueExamplePost(HiddenValueModel modelWithHiddenValue)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

***`When Bind From Controller:`***

```
public IActionResult HiddenValueExample()
        {
            var hiddenExamVal = new HiddenValueModel();
            hiddenExamVal.HiddenValueId = 10101;
            hiddenExamVal.HiddenValueName = "Test Hidden Value";

            return View(hiddenExamVal);
        }
```

***`Bind From Controller and submit that value again to controller:`***

In this case update the view like this :

```cs
@model MVCApps.Models.HiddenValueModel


@{ ViewBag.Title = " "; }

<h2>Hidden Value Example </h2>
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm("HiddenValueExamplePost", "StackOverFlow"))
{


    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr><th>HiddenValueName </th><td id="HiddenValueName"> @Html.TextBoxFor(r => Model.HiddenValueName, new { @class = "form-control" })</td></tr>
        <tr><th>HiddenValue Id Which Is Hidden</th><td id="HiddenValueId">@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HiddenValueId, new { @value = Model.HiddenValueId} )<br /></tr>
    </table>


    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:1091px" />
}
<br />
```

***`Output Using Backend Binding:`***

[image]

Hope it would guided you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Hidden Field in ASP .NET MVC

Studentmodel:

```
public class Student{
public int StudentId { get; set; }
public string StudentName { get; set; }}
```

HiddenFor() in Razor View:

@model Student
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StudentId)

Html Result :

```
<input data-val="true"
 data-val-number="The field StudentId must be a number."
 data-val-required="The StudentId field is required."
 id="StudentId"
 name="StudentId"
 type="hidden"
 value="" />
```

Html.Hidden() :

```
@model Student
@Html.Hidden("StudentId")
```

Html Result :

```
<input id="StudentId" name="StudentId" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Helper (@Html.Hidden())**

If you want a Hidden Field with its value set you can try this:

```
@Html.Hidden("Jeremy", "Thompson")
```

The Hidden Field's name will be "Jeremy", and the value of the Hidden Field will be "Thompson".

**Strongly Typed Helper (@Html.HiddenFor()) / Model Binding**

The strongly typed helper contains 2 parameters:

1. Hidden Field name which is the name of a Model Property.
2. Value of Hidden Field (if we want to set the value from the view).

Declaration of Hidden Field using strongly typed helper:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StudentID, new { Value = "1" })
```

[Ref](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/create-or-use-hidden-fields-in-asp-net-mvc-with-html-helpers-example)

Comment: Hello @Jeremy, in this way `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StudentID, new { Value = "1" })`  while you post that value to the controller did you get the value as expected? I am asking because sometimes we might not get the value.